# Android - declaring namespace of my own app

Tags: java, android

Hey, I tried to declare my own namespace, and use attrs.xml for holding some of attributes i need in application, but it just wont see my namespace.
in Manifest file I have

> manifest
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   package="com.gierca"
>   android:versionCode="1"
>   android:versionName="1.0"

and so on..
and in my layout.xml I declared namespace as

> LinearLayout
>     xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.gierca"
>     myapp:attribute="some_string"

autofill doesnt work with this namespace, and it just doesnt work either.
What am I doing wrong? I tried googling this, but even when I find some examples, they seem to be doing same thing as I do, and Im clueless

Comment: I don't think autocomplete will work with custom namespaces, but you shouldn't get any errors. Does your layout validate correctly?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with layout, but in this way I tried to set some attribute, it just doesnt kick in.

Comment: My point was that if it wasn't recognizing your attribute, then the layout editor would throw an error and not let you build the app.